# Form Field Containers

Tags: theming

How do I get rid of the outer box around the location field for example. I don't like how the location title + background colours are repeated twice for additional fields.

I have this issue on every template, not just the one displayed so can answers please be generic so I can do it on every template.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Drupal uses renderable arrays, so there is probably something like this:

```
'location_outter' => array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => 'location',
  'location_inner' => array(
     '#type' => 'fieldset',
     '#title' => 'location',
     'city' => array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'City',
     ),
   ),
);
```

So i think you can, if it is form, try use alter hook, for example `yourmodule_user_form_alter` and modify that renderable array.